# How to recalculate the value of image size

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a small calculation issue with Flutter / Dart.

**What I need** I need to recalculate the value of an image size and width proportionally.

**Example:** I have an image with the following resolution: 5000x4000px. I want to recalculate the size of this image to achieve that the width and height are less than 2000px. So the result should be 2000x1600px in this case.

**What I tried**

```
List<int> fpBytes = File(firstPicture).readAsBytesSync();
image.Image firstPictureData = image.decodeImage(fpBytes);
int fpWidth = firstPictureData.width;
int fpHeight = firstPictureData.height;

print(fpWidth);
print(fpHeight);

// Resize proportionally
if (fpWidth > 2000 || fpHeight > 2000) {
  var diffWidth = fpWidth - 2000;
  var diffHeight = fpHeight - 2000;
  fpWidth = fpWidth - diffWidth;
  fpHeight = fpHeight - diffHeight;
}

print(fpWidth);
print(fpHeight);
```

**The console log**

```
flutter: 4224
flutter: 2376
flutter: 2000
flutter: 2000
```

I know. My calculation has a very wrong logic. But I don't know how can I calculate this scenario. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be calculated arithmetically and is nothing specific to Dart or Flutter.

```dart
// First check if width is too large
if (fpWidth > 2000) {
  // If so, find out how many times too large it is 
  // and divide both width and height proportionally.
  double d = fpWidth / 2000;
  fpWidth = fpWidth / d;
  fpHeight = fpHeight / d; 
}

// Do the same thing with the height. 
// This way we will be able to handle both landscape and portrait images.
if (fpHeight > 2000) {
  double d = fpHeight / 2000;
  fpWidth = fpWidth / d;
  fpHeight = fpHeight / d; 
}

print(fpWidth);
print(fpHeight);
```

However, you can also let the Flutter framework handle the computation for you. Have a look at [BoxFit.scaleDown](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html) for instance. Something like:

```dart
Container(
  height: 2000,
  width: 2000,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  image: DecorationImage(
     image: AssetImage(firstPicture),
     fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    ),
  ),
);
```